# Karma giving error Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef! after upgrade from v7 to v8

Tags: angular, karma-runner

Very similar to my last Karma upgrade issue [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67833902/angular-karma-error-after-upgrading-angular-from-v7-to-v8), I have all my unit test for a component failing after upgrading from v7 to v8. Once again due to a custom component from a shared library.

So here I get the following..

```
        NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ProgressIndicatorComponent -> ElementRef]: 
        StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ProgressIndicatorComponent -> ElementRef]: 
            NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
    Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
            at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:725:1) [angular]
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11918:1) [angular]
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11862:1) [angular]
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11764:1) [angular]
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11918:1) [angular]
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11862:1) [angular]
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:11764:1) [angular]
            at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20234:1) [angular]
            at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20905:1) [angular]
            at resolveDep (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:21276:1) [angular]
            at createClass (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:21152:1) [angular]
            at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:21027:1) [angular]
            at createViewNodes (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:29387:1) [angular]
            at callViewAction (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:29703:1) [angular]
```

but this time I do have the `ProgressIndicatorComponent` (the problem component here) in my declarations.

The component has the following constructor.

```
    constructor(
        private elRef: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

If I import the module containing this component instead (and remove it from the declarations) I get

```
    Failed: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'visible' since it isn't a known property of 'mm-progress-indicator'.
    1. If 'my-progress-indicator' is an Angular component and it has 'visible' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

If I include both, ie import the module AND declare the component, I get..

```
    NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ProgressIndicatorComponent -> ElementRef]: 
        StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ProgressIndicatorComponent -> ElementRef]: 
            NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
```

Now out of ideas (the missing declaration worked for me last time)

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

This time, adding the following to `tsconfig.json` seemed to fix the issue

```
"paths": {     
     "@angular/*": [
       "./node_modules/@angular/*"
     ],
```

My global angular cli is actually still at v7, perhaps it was trying to use this?
Also not sure why only the unit tests needed this, where as the project would build and run fine.